# Запятая перед 'как' с устойчивым выражением

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед `как` в случае, представленном ниже?

> Уровень верховой езды: езжу, как Бог, в которого никто не верит.

Мнения расходятся. Кто-то говорит, что это обычное сравнение - запятая нужна. Я же думаю, что запятая не нужна: `как Бог` - это устойчивое выражение (сродни фразеологизму). К тому же можно заменить одним словом - превосходно, отлично, безупречно и т.п. Так как всё же правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Уровень верховой езды: езжу как бог (в которого никто не верит).**

**1) Употребление прописной буквы** [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=Бог](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3)

4. чего, какой. О предмете поклонения, восхищения (обычно одарённом человеке, гении). Бог поэзии, музыки кто-л. Да это же кулинарный бог!

**2) Оборот обособляется** при сравнении и не обособляется в значении "божественно".

Примеры:

И танцевал **как бог**. [Дина Сабитова. Где нет зимы (2011)]
А в качалку заглянул этот, негр…  Зубы ― мел, глазами сверкает, красив как бог… или как чёрт? [Иван Наумов. Мумбачья площадка (2007)]

Он, свой роман в уме построив, Летит домой, не чуя ног, И там судьбой своих героев Распоряжается, **как бог**. [Александр Кушнер. Первое впечатление // «Звезда», 2003]

Answer (score 0):

**Уровень верховой езды: езжу, как Бог, в которого никто не верит.**

Я считаю, что сравнение "как Бог, в которого никто не верит" говорит о посредственном умении ездить, а не о превосходном. То есть кто-то ездит как [нормальный] Бог, ну а кто-то так не умеет. Поскольку это выражение не является устойчивым, я предлагаю поставить запятую. В Вашей трактовке утверждение выглядит несогласованным и его лучше исправить следующим образом:

**Езжу как Бог (в которого никто не верит).**

Или ещё вариант (с другим смыслом):

**Езжу как Бог, но этому никто не верит.**

Comment: "Бог" с заглавной буквы пишется только в предположении его единственности, поэтому противопоставление бога, в которого верят, такому, в которого не верят, возможно только при написании с маленькой - в противном случае остаётся ваш второй вариант (после "Бога" - пристёгнутая просто так присказка, мол остальные не верят в упомянутого мной Бога).

Comment: @Alex_ander Это понятно, и я думал над этим. Я решил, что автор вопроса (или предложения) вполне вправе считать, что существует только один Бог, но в него никто не верит. Иначе я не могу интерпретировать это предложение. Но соответствующего устойчивого выражения нет.